# Registering a Key Press like a button click in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, events, keypress, basic

I am attempting to create a simple program that changes the image in a picture box upon keydown, and changes back when the key is up. I've already had a look online and tried a few things from various forum posts, but none of them seem to be working in the current way I am applying them.
Here is the original code I made myself:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    While True
        If Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.D1 Then
            PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.balloon_glow
        ElseIf Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.D2 Then
            PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.balloon_glow
        ElseIf Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.D3 Then
            PictureBox3.Image = My.Resources.balloon_glow
        Else
            PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.balloon_dark
            PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.balloon_dark
            PictureBox3.Image = My.Resources.balloon_dark
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

And here my current version of the code after a few different attempts at things:

```
Private Sub KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.D1) Then
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.balloon_glow
    ElseIf e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.D2) Then
        PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.balloon_glow
    ElseIf e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.D3) Then
        PictureBox3.Image = My.Resources.balloon_glow
    Else
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.balloon_dark
        PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.balloon_dark
        PictureBox3.Image = My.Resources.balloon_dark
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Call KeyPress(sender, e)
End Sub
```

So, overall, I've tried a few different syntax's, and different ways with loops and procedures, but nothing seems to be working. Is there anyone that could possibly get this to a working position for me and explain it? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried PictureBox1_Keypress() Handles PictureBox1.KeyPress fuction?

Comment: Good luck! Hope it helps you out!

Comment: Tried `Private Sub PictureBox1_Keypress(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.KeyPress  
        If Control.ModifierKeys = Keys.D1 Then  
            PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.balloon_glow   
        Else  
            PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.balloon_dark  
        End If  
    End Sub`
However, no luck. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Try e.Keys or something instead of Control.ModifierKeys.

Comment: Dont have a computer at my side to check actual code for yah.

Comment: You definitely can't have an infinite loop like that in your event handler!  Hopefully you've already figured that out...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of exactly what you are trying to do, but this might help...

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.D1) Then
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.balloon_glow
    ElseIf e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.D2) Then
        PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.balloon_glow
    ElseIf e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.D3) Then
        PictureBox3.Image = My.Resources.balloon_glow
    Else
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.balloon_dark
        PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.balloon_dark
        PictureBox3.Image = My.Resources.balloon_dark
    End If
End Sub
```

You may want something similar in Form1_KeyUp if you want them to revert back immediately.

Comment: You may need to use KeyPreview() form property. The point of the above is to add the "Handles me.KeyDown" to the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out...holding down more than one of them in combination and releasing one of them:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.D1
            PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.balloon_glow

        Case Keys.D2
            PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.balloon_glow

        Case Keys.D3
            PictureBox3.Image = My.Resources.balloon_glow

    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.D1
            PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.balloon_dark

        Case Keys.D2
            PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.balloon_dark

        Case Keys.D3
            PictureBox3.Image = My.Resources.balloon_dark

    End Select
End Sub
```